# Capture the resource group value into variable

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, command-line-interface

I am looking at automating Azure SQL database backup restore process and I would like to use AZ CLI command to extract the value of the resource group the Azure SQL Server is in.

Would someone know how I can get the value of the resource group in a variable if I provide the server name to the following command

```
az sql server list --query "[?name=='somesqlserver']"
```

This lists all the information of the server however I need only the resource group extracted in a variable. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to just get the list as JSON, convert it to Powershell, and filter it there, like this:

```
az sql server list | 
  ConvertFrom-Json | 
  Where-Object name -eq 'somesqlserver' | 
  Select-Object name, resourceGroup
```